# Wix Conditional custom action

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a Wix project which has several msi and a bootstrapper to run these msi.

In one of this msi, I want to run a custom action based in a parameter property.

In my `Product.wxs`, I have this code:

```
<CustomAction Id="MyAction" FileKey="myapp.exe" ExeCommand="-a -b" 
              Execute="deferred" Return="check" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    ...
    <Custom Action="MyAction" After="CustomActionInstallService">
        NOT Installed AND NOT PATCH AND MYPROPERTY=1
    </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

From command line I run:

```
mybootstrapper MYPROPERTY=1
```

But the custom action doesn't run.

For testing, I have change my custom action like this:

```
    <Custom Action="MyAction" After="CustomActionInstallService">
        MYPROPERTY=1
    </Custom>
```

with the same result, the custom action doesn't run.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share a log-file? Is CustomActionInstallService called? Have you tried MYPROPERTY="1"

Comment: Why are you using a custom action to install your service instead of using ServiceInstall/ServiceControl?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter this is only a name for this action. Not more. The proble is with the conditions

Comment: I'm just checking there isn't a design problem also.  My hunch is that there is.  I try to provide comprehensive advice and solve the big picture problems.

Comment: What does your Property element look like?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you explain more in detail?

Answer (score 0):

Within your bootstrapper (burn) script are you passing the property to the MSI? Something like this should be done within your burn project to pass down the property:

```
<Bundle>
    <Variable Name="MYPROPERTY" bal:Overridable="yes"/>
    <Chain>
      <MsiPackage>
        <MsiProperty Name="MYPROPERTY" Value="[MYPROPERTY]"/>
      </MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
</Bundle>
```

Comment: You are just guessing as the there isn't enough information in the question to provide an answer.   The problem could also be that he hasn't declared MYPROPERTY as Secure.

Comment: Since there's no indication where CustomInstallService is called, it might even be before InstallFiles, so of course a deferred CA of a file being installed will fail.